# Is it acceptable to not put my 5 months work experience in a resume?

Tags: interviewing, resume, job-change

I am resigning from my first job. But the problem is, I just worked for 5 months.

When I make my resume, should I include the 5 months experience?

I'm worried an interviewer will think that I'm a job hopper? But if I don't include it, will it seem like cheating?

Comment: [This answer](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/a/14550/2322)  exactly answers this situation too. What details are different between your situations? Also, I've edited your question somewhat to focus on the question you are asking - hopefully this makes what you are looking for more clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since this is your first job, it would very rarely make sense not to list it.  If you omit it, you'd have no work experience listed.  Having a few months of experience would generally be better than having no experience.  There is no general requirement that you include every job you've ever had on your resume but omitting the only job you've had would generally be a mistake.

Of course, the fact that you resigned after just five months will likely hurt you in the eyes of a potential new employer, it's just that the penalty for having no employment over the past 5 months is likely to be higher.  How badly you'll be affected will depend on the industry and your location and what an "average" job tenure for someone in that industry in that location looks like.  A good computer programmer in Silicon Valley, a welder in Ohio, and a fast food worker in Vancouver might all have very different expectations about how long each of their positions ought to last.

It is not clear whether you have already submitted your resignation or if you are planning to resign.  If you are planning to resign, I'd suggest that you keep the job while you look for a new one rather than resigning if that is at all possible.  You'll look like a stronger candidate to potential employers now if you're actively employed and your resume in the future will look much stronger if you went from one job to another immediately rather than having 5 months of employment followed by a period of unemployment before you land your next job.

Comment: well, thanks...
I have send the resignation letter to my employer, now planning to find a new job...
your explanation had clear my doubt...